# Левую кнопку в Navigation Bar сдвинуть левее

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar

Кастомную UIBarButtonItem кнопку Back в UINavigationBar нужно подвинуть левее, чем она есть по дефолту. Код ниже сдвигает картинку на кнопке, но не саму кнопку (см. изображение ниже).

Каким образом можно подвинуть не только изображение, но и саму кнопку?

[image: кнопка]

```
const CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44., 44.);
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];

button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -6., 0, 0); // здесь получается сдвинуть влево картинку на кнопке, но не саму кнопку

// [button addTarget:self action:someSelector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

Comment: Ты можешь попробовать использовать ответ [данный тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866062/can-i-change-the-position-of-navigationbar-item)

Comment: @K.Davydenko не дает эффекта...  во всяком случае в iOS 11

Answer (score 2):

Из последнего рабочего делал таким способом:

```
func findAndMoveButtonsStackView(_ testView: UIView?) {
    guard let view = testView, String(describing: type(of: view)) != "_UIButtonBarStackView" else {
        testView?.frame.origin.x -= 15 // на сколько хотим подвинуть
        return
    }
    view.subviews.forEach({ [weak self] in self?.findAndMoveButtonsStackView($0) })
}

// и вызываем:
findAndMoveButtonsStackView(navigationController?.navigationBar)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ibb.co/niPXNc не получается ( что не так делаю?